# How does Outer Space in the Duckverse differ from our universe?

Tags: ducktales, donald-duck

In the latest Ducktales episode we find out that:

> Della Duck got lost in outer space due to a cosmic storm.

I don't know what a cosmic storm and don't think we have that in our universe.
The Duckverse also seems to be different than our universe in that spacetravel is way more common.

What else do we know about the Duckverse in regards to outer space?

All comics, shows etc are canon.

Comment: Technically, we have several types of [cosmic storm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_storm) in our universe.

Comment: Well, for starters they have anthropomorphic talking ducks...

Comment: @gowenfawr But none of those "cosmic storms" resemble Earth storms.  The matter in those "cosmic storms" is usually many orders of magnitude less dense than the thinnest vacuum that can be made by modern science.  So a space ship could travel through a "cosmic storm" without noticing anything as far as turbulence goes. and if the radiation that might be in the "cosmic storm" can penetrate the ship's hull and they don't have radiation detectors running, they could pick up a fatal dose of radiation without noticing anything.  "Cosmic storms" are totally different from Earth storms.